# When was the Binance ICO?

Tags: ico-initial-coin-offering, binance

Writing a research article on Binance, and I'm trying to work out when their ICO was, and when they opened doors to their trading platform. Does anyone have an authoritative source for this?

I can see on Crunchbase that they raised 10m USD in 2018, and it also lists an ICO in September, although some ICO websites claim their ICO was Dec 31, and others in July. Sites seems to agree the ICO was 15m USD.

Is there an authoritative source for when Binance started, and when and for how long their ICO ran?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about bitcoin.

Comment: @Anonymous sure you are. But these questions are allowed - you should familiarise yourself with the site faq https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [BNB whitepaper](https://resource.bnbstatic.com/books/20180119/1516332231061.pdf), written by Binance, the Binance project started on 2017/06/14, the ICO started on 2017/07/01 and the ICO finished on 2017/07/21.

Comment: https://www.binance.com/resources/ico/Binance_WhitePaper_en.pdf